# How to change background image on tap on a drop-down list?

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to change the background image on tap on a drop down list, that i will tap on BG 1 and the image will change, how can i access single element of my drop-down list? here is my code ,  how can i do this ?

```
    new Column( children: <Widget>[
            new Padding(
                padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(100.0, 350.0, 100.0, 50.0)),
            new DropdownButton<String>(
              onChanged: (String value) {
                setState(() {
                  return new Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(100.0, 10.0, 100.0, 00.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: new AssetImage('asset/bg.png'),
                alignment: Alignment.topRight,
              ),
            ),
          );
                });
              },
              hint: new Text('Select Type'),
              value: selectedValues,
              items: <String>[
                "BG 1",
                "BG 2",
              ].map((String value) {
                return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: value,
                  child: new Text(value),
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),

          ],),
        ImageRotate(),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a variable which hold the value of DropdownButton selected item and create an List of AssetImage. I hope that Following example clear your idea.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Firebase Auth Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  List<String> _locations = ['A', 'B'];
  int imageindex = 0;
  String _selcted = 'A';
  List<ImageProvider> bg = [ AssetImage("images/p1.png"), AssetImage("images/p2.jpg")];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("cds"),
      ),
      body:  Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(image: bg[imageindex])
        ),
        child: Center(
          child:new DropdownButton<String>(
            items: _locations.map((String value) {
              return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                child: new Text(value),
              );
            }).toList(),
            hint: new Text("csdc"),
            value: _selcted,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _selcted = value;
                imageindex = _locations.indexOf(value);
              });
            },
          )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much , it really did what i wanted to be , Thanks Again

Comment: Accept and upvote the answer so it is use full for other.